# Drawing directed planar graph in Maple

Tags: graph, maple

I am trying to plot a directed planar graph in Maple but the command only accepts undirected graphs. The documentation does not mention this restriction. Is there a way to plot them in maple?

A small working example:

```
restart:
with(GraphTheory):
G:=Graph({{1,2},{2,3},{3,4}});
DrawPlanar(G);
```

This works but defines an undirected graph. By changing the {1,2} to [1,2], the edge is made directional and the DrawPlanar fails.
Does anyone know how to create a planar plot of a directed graph?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `GraphTheory:-DrawGraph` command.

The various display options of the `DrawGraph` command will not produce something laid out exactly like how `DrawPlanar` would do it.

I don't know of any reason for `DrawPlanar` to not support directed graphs; it just seems to be how it is programmed. I would suppose that `DrawPlanar` could be (re)programmed to use instead a mix of `HasArc` and `HasEdge` commands, etc, and attain the broader functionality.

Comment: The whole point of my code is to get a planar representation.DrawGraph would just give a random representation, no guarantees for anything to be planar. The options allow to specify styles but when I ask for a planar graph it redirects the call to DrawPlanar. I don't think me as a user could reprogram any of the routines.